# How to initialise array of dictionary keys based on the values of the dictionary keys

Tags: swift

How can I initialise an array of filtered keys based on the values for the keys?

In this case I want to return all the elements that are 'true' which are: ["red", "green"]

```
var selectedColors = [
    "blue":   false,
    "red":    true,
    "yellow": false,
    "green":  true,
    "black":  false,
]
```

so basically I want to achieve this:

```
//PSUEDO CODE
var trueColors = selectedColours.selectKeysWhereValIsTrue()
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, feel free to let me know what's wrong with the question...

Answer (score 4):

```swift
selectedColors.filter{ $1 }.map{ $0.key }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `.filter { $1 }.keys` is more readable (and probably a better go-to), it's worth noting that you can do both operations in one using `compactMap`, which might get you some performance gains if you have big data sets:

```
let trueColors = selectedColors.compactMap { color, bool in
    bool ? color : nil
}
```

Comment: Another advantage is that is saves the useless allocation of an intermediate dictionary (of filtered elements), so this can be way faster than filtering + map.

Comment: @LouisLac But it's less clear, which is almost always more expensive than small changes like that. That's why I say `.filter { $1 }.keys` is probably a better choice, unless we're taking about data sets of 10,000s or more

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
let res = Array(selectedColors.filter { $0.value }.keys) // ["red", "green"]
```

Comment: thank you, but just out of interest, what would you change in order to get all the keys with false value

Comment: @v0lk Just invert the predicate. `$0.value` is just a boolean. `filter` keeps items for which its predicate evaluates to true. To keeps falses, just invert it: `.filter { !$0.value }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let trueColors = selectedColors.filter({ $0.value }).keys
```